# AdvancedDataGrid runtime errors when compiled in library

Tags: apache-flex

I am attempting to move a control built with the AdvancedDataGrid from an SWF module to an SWC module.

However, this gives me a runtime error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at mx.controls::AdvancedDataGridBaseEx/getLockedContent()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\advancedgrids\src\mx\controls\AdvancedDataGridBaseEx.as:4430]
```

I am using Flex 4.5 SDK.

My modules do not show any warning during compilation.

Looking into the framework code around line 4430 we see:

```
        private function getLockedContent():Sprite
        {
            var locked:Sprite = Sprite(listContent.getChildByName("lockedContent"));
            if (!locked)
            {
```

So I am guessing that the listContent which is from the parent class has not been initialized correctly.

```
/**
 *  An internal display object that parents all of the item renderers,
 *  selection and highlighting indicators and other supporting graphics.
 *  This is roughly equivalent to the <code>contentPane</code> in the 
 *  Container class, and is used for managing scrolling.
 *  
 *  @langversion 3.0
 *  @playerversion Flash 9
 *  @playerversion AIR 1.1
 *  @productversion Flex 3
 */
protected var listContent:AdvancedListBaseContentHolder;
```

Does anybody know the cause of this and how to fix?

Comment: Are you sharing the full stack trace?  You should be able to "go back" in the stack trace to help diagnose the error.  Also, if you could share a sample that demonstrates the problem; that'd be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you www.Flextras.com.   When I tried to create a sample the problem was not present - so on further digging I believe the problem was a result of synchronisation issues in our complex code.